# How to make it so that all available data is being pulled instead of specifically typing out a date range for this script?

Tags: python, yfinance

The available options dates are below. How can I write a code so that it pulls all those dates instead of having to type them all out in a separate row?

`2022-03-11, 2022-03-18, 2022-03-25, 2022-04-01, 2022-04-08, 2022-04-14, 2022-04-22, 2022-05-20, 2022-06-17, 2022-07-15, 2022-10-21, 2023-01-20, 2024-01-19`

```
import yfinance as yf

gme = yf.Ticker("gme")

opt = gme.option_chain('2022-03-11')

print(opt)
```

Comment: Is this in the interval of 7 days between one date to the other?

Comment: I think it's only an interval of 7 days for certain options dates, but not always true to 7 days due to holidays/events, etc...

edit: however, the command gme.options does get the dates for ALL the available dates - is there a way to incorporate the .options command into the option_chain one?

Comment: If you require specific dates, it's a must you need to type it out into a `list`. But have you thought about using loop to get what you want? As I have worked with multiple tickers before, yet to work with multiple dates

Comment: Could you please give me an example of a loop for this specific scenario? When I search google for loop information, it seems very different/"simple" for a lack of better words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as these dates have no regular pattern, you should create a list of the dates.

```
list1=['2022-03-11', '2022-03-18', '2022-03-25', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-08', '2022-04-14', '2022-04-22', '2022-05-20', '2022-06-17', '2022-07-15', '2022-10-21', '2023-01-20', '2024-01-19']
```

After you have created the list, you can initiate your code as how you have done:

```
import yfinance as yf

gme = yf.Ticker("gme")
```

But right now, since you would want to have everything being printed out, and I assume you would need to save it to file for a better view (as I have checked the output and I personally prefer csv for `yfinance`), you can do this:

```
for date in list1:
    df = gme.option_chain(date)
    df_call = df[0]
    df_put = df[1]
    df_call.to_csv(f'call_{date}.csv')
    df_put.to_csv(f'put_{date}.csv')
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for explaining it to me like this. I tried your method and it worked. Do you mind explaining why my new method didn't pull the same results? I get the error: 'tuple' object is not callable.



import yfinance as yf
list1=['2022-03-11', '2022-03-18', '2022-03-25', '2022-04-01', '2022-04-08', '2022-04-14', '2022-04-22', '2022-05-20', '2022-06-17', '2022-07-15', '2022-10-21', '2023-01-20', '2024-01-19']
gme = yf.Ticker("gme")
expdates = gme.options(list1)
opt =  gme.option_chain(list1)

#print(expdates)

print(opt)

Comment: Also, do you think that it's better for me to append the data in python first before exporting the results to .csv, so that I can just get 1 or 2 csv files?

Comment: As you can see in the `gme.option_chain`, the output is actually a tuple of two dataframes (call and put), that's why it's not going to be called unless you break it down into two dataframes, as in the answer above. On the other hand, don't append it because Python's memory will be overload.

Comment: Oh, I see. I think you're referencing the two dataframes:
df_call = df[0]
df_put = df[1]

If that's the case, it makes more sense to me now... I'll have to dive more into it. Thanks again for your help/explanations!